# How to stay in the UK for more than 6 months?

Tags: visas, uk, long-stay-visas

I am a US citizen and thus can stay in the UK for 6 months.  I am purchasing a live-aboard cruising boat to tour the UK via canals and rivers.  I'd like to be able to stay for 10 to 12 months before I move the boat to Holland?  How do I extend the 6 months - What kind of Visa do I need to apply for.  This is strictly for tourism.    I've been on the UK websites - the only things I can find tells me I do not need a visa.

Comment: @pnuts: Well, for starters, there's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Kingdom), which says that US citizens "are visa-exempt for stays in the UK of up to 6 months".

Comment: @pnuts - Most web information about USA to UK travel mentions that US citizens can stay in the UK for up to six months for both tourism and business purposes.

Comment: I think the UK has arbitrarily decided that someone wanting to stay longer than 6 months is not a visitor (unless they are getting medical treatment). You could leave and try to reenter but this is obviously risky. There used to be a visa for "Retired Persons of Independent Means", but no longer. A British grandparent and Commonwealth citizenship can still provide an easy long stay, I think. Everything else I know of is harder.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  ("Can a US'er have an actual holiday of say 12 months in the UK?")  It would be fascinating to know the answer.  **BTW Claire.**  You really don't want to be in the UK for 12 months ;)  Hint: France is a day's sailing away.  *runs away*

Comment: Just BTW - *"I am purchasing a live-aboard cruising boat to tour the UK via canals and rivers"* I'm surprised there is a "cruising boat" (ie a cruiser, a boat you can do things with like "go to Italy") which is also usable on "canals" ..... what sort of stinkboat is it??!

Comment: It apparently is possible, with a lot of skill and luck, to take a narrow boat across the English Chanel. See [Retired couple conquer the Channel in a canal boat](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1451294/Retired-couple-conquer-the-Channel-in-a-canal-boat.html)

Comment: Getting landed with 6 months leave-to-enter is not automatic.

Comment: Boat is a Replica Dutch Barge.

Comment: These Barges can be built to Categoy C to offer River, Coastal and Canal waterways.  They can also cross the Channel.   - Patricia ... If this narrow board story is the one I read previously - I wouldn't want to attempt that!

Comment: @pnuts I was just surprised it was even possible. Growing up in England I saw a lot of narrow boats, and did not think they would be stable enough for open sea. It looks as though the OP is going with a wider, more stable vessel which will limit which canals they can use in England.

Answer (score 7):

Normally, US citizens can only visit without a visa for no more than six months. Some countries allow visitors to apply for a visa to stay for longer. However, that does not appear to be true for the UK. From [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa):

> ## How long you can stay
>
> You can usually stay in the UK for up to 6 months.
>
> You might be able to stay for longer if:
>
> - you’re coming to the UK for private medical treatment - up to 11 months
> - you’re an academic on sabbatical and coming to the UK for research - you, your spouse or civil partner may be able to stay for up to 12 months

Staying for 10 to 12 months is outside what is permitted under a Standard Visitor visa. As far as I am aware, there is no other visa that would permit tourism activities for more than six months.

Although US citizens do not need a visa for visits up to six months, you will still be interviewed by an immigration officer (ECO, Entry Clearance Officer). They do have the power to refuse entry to you if they believe you are arriving to live in the UK (and if you say "live-aboard cruising boat" that sure sounds like you intend to live in the UK).

Comment: There's no reason to hedge with language like 'seems like'. There are no provisions in the rules to extend permission full stop end of story.  I would also suggest a cautionary note to the OP that the BIG 'elephant in the room' is getting landed in the first instance (no ties, regulated activities, onward travel), much less trying to extend. Please ping me if you edit so that I can vote.

Comment: With the above information it sounds like I need to apply for a true Visa.  I will go forth with the help of an immigration/visa company.

Comment: @Claire locate a practitioner using ILPA http://www.ilpa.org.uk/pages/find-immigration-advice.html or the Law Society http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/

Comment: @Claire don't forget to mark Greg's answer as 'accepted' by putting the green check mark on it.  I can vote on it later, thanks.

Comment: @GayotFow: Thanks for the support, I've edited my answer with additional information.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not sure "live-aboard boat" sounds worse than "vacation home", yet I know IOs seem to treat the latter as a perfectly unremarkable reason to be visiting regularly. I think only the stay length is particularly problematic.